# WebBrowser control without loading a document from file

Tags: c#, .net, xml, browser

I have a scenario where i would like to show some object's description (which is currently stored in XML format) on a WebBrowser control.

The object is already serialized into memory, and i would like to avoid reading it again from file for display purposes on the WebBrowser control.

The reason for going this way is we would like to use XSL to format this object's presentation the way we like (and to have flexibility in doing so).

To do this, i would like to (somehow) inject the object's xml as string into the WebBrowser.

Can this be achieved? is there a better option for handling this scenario?

Answer (score 0):

You could try handing it a [data URL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_URI_scheme) containing an encoded version of your XML. Not sure if this will work, or what the limitations on size are.

Answer (score 0):

Make a quick browser extension to communicate with your application? The downside would be the extension will have to be installed as well and you'd have to make a separate extension for all major browsers.